# Not able to access GRPC java server(springboot) in HA docker environment

Tags: docker, grpc-java

I have been implemented GRPC server and client both working fine in local windows env .
once after promoting GRPC server app(implemented in spring boot)  to docker Linux environment I could not able to invoke grpc server app from my local grpc client app. After deployment I able to see my sysouts while starting grpc server app , here I am printing ip address  , but I could not able to invoke grpc server using ip and port, any suggestions appreciated .

Regards
Dav

Comment: Can you show your client side code: how you are creating a channel and a stub to send the rpc to the server?

Comment: client i am using node js:            var port = process.env.PORT || 9081;
let packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(
    PROTO_PATH, {
        keepCase: true,
        longs: String,
        enums: String,
        defaults: true,
        oneofs: true
    }); let mbrdetails_proto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition).mbrdetails;
function main() {
    /*

 const root_cert = fs.readFileSync('path/to/root-cert');
 const ssl_creds = grpc.credentials.createSsl(root_cert);
const stub = new helloworld.Greeter('myservice.example.com', ssl_creds);

Comment: */
    let client = new mbrdetails_proto.Mbrdetails('34.119.37.61:'+port,
        grpc.credentials.createInsecure());

    let call = client.mbrDetails(function(error, response) {
        console.log("Reports successfully generated for in client: ", response.successmsg);

    });

Comment: Sorry I thought the client was grpc java as well. You may want to add grpc-nodejs tag to get the attention of relevant folks.

Comment: thank you for your response.. i have written java client now    , local it is successfully invoking local java grpc server where as after deploy docker test environment  failing
public class GrpcClient { public static void main(String[] args) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("10.28.45.00", 9081).usePlaintext().build();
  MebrdtlRequest request = MebrdtlRequest.newBuilder().setMsg("test...").build();
  mbrdetailsBlockingStub stubmber =mbrdetailsGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
  
  stubmber.getmbrdetails(request); } }

Comment: getting this error  Exception in thread "main" io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
 at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:233)
 at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:214)
 at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:139)
 at com.member.grpc.mbrdetailsGrpc$mbrdetailsBlockingStub.getmbrdetails(mbrdetailsGrpc.java:211)
 at GrpcClient.main(GrpcClient.java:18)